# ngFor in html table not working for jsPDF autotable

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

html

```
 <table border="1" id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Dish</th>
              <th scope="col">quantity</th>
              <th scope="col">Price</th>
              <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <div *ngFor="let d of list[x]">
                      <tr *ngFor="let dish of d">
                        <td>{{dish.name}}</td>
                       <td>{{dish.quantity}}</td>
                       <td>{{dish.price}}</td>
                       <td>{{dish.price * dish.quantity}}</td>
                      </tr>
              </div>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

ts

```
 generateBill(){
    let doc = new jsPDF();
     autoTable(doc, {html: '#myTable'});
    doc.save("order.pdf");
  }
```

[this is the output I get from the above code Only heading is get reflected Body part is not showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtLha.png)

Ngfor is not working for the jspdf autotable.
the body part of HTML table got reflected in the browser but not showing in the generated pdf.

Comment: How and when you calling generateBill()

Comment: Try this `doc.autoTable({
      html: '#myTable',
      startY: 30,
      showHead: 'everyPage',
    });`

    doc.save('table.pdf');

Comment: Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'  Getting this error for this code    doc.autoTable(
      {       html: '#myTable',       
      startY: 30,       
      showHead: 'everyPage',     
    });

Comment: Can share this issue on stackblitz.com. and share link here

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qfl9jv?file=src%2Fapp%2Forders%2Forders.component.ts

Comment: Its not working example. Add some dummy data. reproduce your pdf problem on stackblitz. You have just copy pasted your code